# How to integrate this integral $\int(1-r)/(1+r)^2$??\

Tags: integration

How to evaluate this integral 
$$\int \frac{1-r}{(1+r)^2} \ \mathrm{d}r$$

I was trying to do by parts however it doesn't seems to work here.

Answer (score 4):

Try partial fraction decomposition: $$\frac{(1-r)}{(1+r)^2} = \frac {A}{1+r} + \frac B{(1+r)^2}$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint

$$\frac{1-r}{(1+r)^2}=\frac{2}{(1+r)^2}-\frac{1}{(1+r)}$$

Comment: Nice to meet you Sami. Short but good hint

Answer (score 3):

Use the substitution $u = 1 + r$, so $1 - r = 2 - u$ and $du = dr$.  The integral becomes
$$
\int \frac{1 - r}{(1 + r)^2} \; dr = \int \frac{2 - u}{u^2} \; du = \int \left( 2u^{-2} - u^{-1} \right) \; du.
$$
Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 2):

rewrite the integrand as
$$\frac{1-r}{(1+r)^2}=\frac{2-(1+r)}{(1+r)^2}=\frac{2}{(1+r)^2}-\frac{1}{(1+r)}$$

Answer (score 1):

A simple substitution will work here. If $u=1+r$ then $\mathrm{d}u=\mathrm{d}r$. This gives
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{1-r}{(1+r)^2} \ \mathrm{d}r &=& \int \frac{2-u}{u^2} \ \mathrm{d}u \\ \\
&=& \int \frac{2}{u^2} - \frac{1}{u} \ \mathrm{d}u \\ \\
&=& -\frac{2}{u}-\ln|u|+c \\ \\
&=& -\frac{2}{1+r}-\ln|1+r|+c\end{eqnarray*}$$